# How is Weight of Evidence actually calculated in category encoders?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, preprocessor, encoder

I am trying to calculate WoE by hand but I am not able to get the same results as calculated by category_encoders WOEEncoder. Here's my dataframe for which I want to calculate scores:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'target': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]})
```

This is the code that I use to calculate WoE Score

```
woe = WOEEncoder(cols=['cat'], random_state=42)
X = df['cat']
y = df.target
encoded_df = woe.fit_transform(X, y)
```

The result for the same is:

```
0   -0.538997
1   0.559616
2   -0.538997
3   0.559616
4   -0.538997
5   -0.538997
6   0.559616
7   0.154151
8   0.154151
```

So,
'a' is encoded as -0.538997
'b' is encoded as 0.559616
'c' is encoded as 0.154151

When I calculate the scores by hand, they are differnt, I take

```
ln(% of non events / % of events).
```

Say for example, for calculating WoE of a,

```
% of non events = targets which are 0 for 'a'/ total targets for group 'a'
```

So, % of non events = 3/4 = 0.75

```
% of events = targets which are 1 for 'a' / total targets for group 'a'
```

```
So, % of events = 1/4 = 0.25

Now, 0.75/0.25 = 3
```

Therefore, WoE(a) = ln(3) = 1.09 which is different from the encoder above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is an open source project, it is possible to see the code of the function:

http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/_modules/category_encoders/woe.html#WOEEncoder

There are two main problems in your code to get similar results to WOEEncoder:

1. WOEEncoder has a parameter 'regularization' with default value 1. You should create a WOEEncoder object with regularization=0 to obtain the same result
2. The second problem is a mistake in your interpretation of the woe formula.
   The right one (which is implemented in WOEEncoder) would be, for the case 'a':

   % of non events = targets which are 0 for 'a' / total targets which are 0

   % of events = targets which are 1 for 'a' / total targets which are 1

   owe = ln(% of events / % of non events )

This produces for the case of 'a':

```
% of non events = 3/5
% of events = 1/4

ln(% of events / % of non events ) = ln(5/12) = -0.8754687373538999
```

If you execute the modified code:

```
woe = WOEEncoder(cols=['cat'], random_state=42, regularization=0)
X = df['cat']
y = df.target
encoded_df = woe.fit_transform(X, y)
```

you will see a similar results:

```
0   -0.875469
1   0.916291
2   -0.875469
3   0.916291
4   -0.875469
5   -0.875469
6   0.916291
7   0.223144
8   0.223144
```